# How to remove multiple files using sftp

Tags: sftp

This post is about removing muliple files from the remote server, when sftp password less connection is setup. I have the code as below. Only first file in the variable `$file_list` gets deleted, when I have the variable set as,

```
$file_list="file1 file2"

sftp $USER@$HOST
rm $file_list
quit
SFTP-Session
```

I even tried executing the commands in prompt mode.

```
sftp $USER@$HOST
rm file1 file2
```

However, I still see that only file1 is getting deleted.

I am not sure if I am missing any basic command.
I tried `mdelete`/`mdel`/`mrm`, which were rejected as *Invalid command* in sftp prompt window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one possible solution that can be added to bash script. This is not ideal as it will make a new connection for each file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# set variables
USER="username"
HOST="hostname"
file_list="file1 file1 file3 file4"
# delete each file
for file in $file_list; do
    echo "rm $file" | sftp $USER@$HOST
done
exit 0
```

**This one-liner is far better!** file1-9 being file names to remove, use a variable if you like, it's the same thing.

```
for file in file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9; do echo -e "rm $file" >> sftp_batch; done; sftp -b sftp_batch username@hostname; rm sftp_batch
```

Comment: What if the files have white spaces in their name?  Will this solution work?

Comment: You can quote the file names. If you have many of them I suggest you look into bash parameter expansion to get best results. Generally for simplicity an admin will not allow filenames with whitespaces and related characters.

Answer (score 3):

I typically use `lftp` to do this.

*Setup - on rmeote server skinner*

```
$ mkdir adir
$ touch afile1 afile2
$ ls
afile1  afile2
```

*now we delete*

```
$ file_list="afile1 afile2"
$ lftp sftp://sam@skinner -e "cd ~/adir; mrm $file_list"
cd ok, cwd=/home/sam/adir    
rm ok, 2 files removed                 
lftp sam@skinner:~/adir> ls
drwxr-xr-x    2 sam      users        4096 Nov  4 11:52 .
drwxr-x---  131 sam      users       20480 Nov  4 11:51 ..
lftp sam@skinner:~/adir> bye
```

To make it a single command:

```
$ lftp sftp://sam@skinner -e "cd ~/adir; mrm $file_list; bye"
```

Comment: I am not able to execute lftp command, may be it requires some library files.

Comment: @bhawna - it may not be installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you can sftp, can you not run ssh?  If so then a command such as:

```
 ssh user@hostname rm file1 file2
```

should work fine.  If you use public/private SSH keys there will be no password prompt.

Comment: Yes it worked, but the above command does not create any log information, and the requirement is to create log as well (Though i didn't specify it in the question).
Thanks

Comment: This is worth pointing out, but having said that, it is quite common for administrators to grant sftp but not ssh access to a server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give a list to the `rm` command in `sftp`, only takes one path as is written in the man page:

```
rm path
    Delete remote file specified by path.
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are the file names. You could delete them using a glob pattern with

```
rm file*
```

Comment: Well, it sure wasn't me.

Comment: I've tried this method and it works if you are using SFTP to access your remote server.