# xargs command is running on local machine but results in an "invalid command" error when run on remote host

Tags: bash, shell-script, remote, sftp

I run this command on my local machine to delete a list of files contained in a text file.

```bsh
xargs rm -r < deletion_list.txt
```

It works as expected and deletes all of the files in the current working directory that are listed in `deletion_list.txt`.

I then use `sftp` to connect to a remote host and create a list of files on my local machine that I want to delete from the remote host.

While connected to the remote host, I enter these commands one by one:

Change local working directory:

```bsh
lcd /home/user/files_to_delete
```

Create a text file in my local working directory of files in the same directory matching the specified pattern:

```bsh
!ls *.txt > deletion_list.txt
```

This is supposed to delete files on the remote host based on the file names in `deletion_list.txt` which is in my local working directory, but it results in an "Invalid Command" error:

```bsh
xargs rm -r < /home/user/files_to_delete/deletion_list.txt
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Are you trying to run `xargs` as a command in the `sftp` session?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes.

Comment: `xargs` is not a valid `sftp` command (see the `sftp` manual).

Comment: Use `ssh` or `telnet` connection.

Comment: Did you use an exclamation mark before the command in the sftp console: `!localshellcommand` ?

Comment: @s3n0 If you are asking whether I used `!xargs rm -r < /home/user/files_to_delete/deletion_list.txt` then I did not. If you are asking if I used a local shell command before the `xargs` command, then yes, the command before it uses `!ls`.

Comment: I mean `!rm -r < /home/user/files_to_delete`, but I don't know where your `files_to_delete` file is located. This should call a local shell (such as `/bin/bash -c "command"`). Another option would be to download the deletion file to the machine, then start deleting the files remotely. BTW, similar questions have already been solved here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165919/how-to-remove-multiple-files-using-sftp (maybe it will help you though this is not the method you require).

Comment: @s3n0 I'm sorry if the question wasn't clear. The `deletion_list.txt` is the file containing the file names I want to delete, and it is in a local directory on my local machine. The files I want to actually delete are in the remote directory. So I want to delete remote files based on the local list. I've updated my question with a new command that doesn't rely on `xargs`.

Comment: `!` will completely execute on the *local* machine. It will use local shell `rm` command, not remote `sftp` `rm`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Everyone can read a man-page. Just type `help` or`? `into the sFTP console. If you want to explain what `!` is for, then you should explain whether it is a "local shell" from the point of view of a server running sFTP service, or whether it is a "local shell" from the point of view of an administrator's machine (from which the administrator has connected to the sFTP server). The term "local" is therefore very misleading from the perspective of computer networks. There is still a problem that sFTP has limited commands and cannot be used as a regular SSH regular connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `sftp` (see `man sftp`) starts

> **DESCRIPTION** sftp is a file transfer program, similar to `ftp`(1), which performs all operations over an encrypted `ssh`(1) transport.

A little later it writes,

> **INTERACTIVE COMMANDS** Once in interactive mode, `sftp` understands a set of commands similar to those of `ftp`(1).

and continues with the set of valid commands (`bye cd chgrp chmod chown df exit get help lcd lls lmkdir ln lpwd ls lumask mkdir progres put pwd quit reget reput rename rm rmdir symlink version ! ?`). The `xargs` command is not amongst that set so you cannot use it inside the `sftp` application. (Note that `!` is a local shell escape, which passes the remainder of the line to a local shell. Such commands are escaped from `sftp` and not processed by it.)

If you really want to use tools like `xargs` you should consider using `ssh` to provide a shell-based session to the remote host. Instead of `sftp user@remotehost` you would use `ssh user@remotehost` (assuming your systems administrator allows interactive sessions, that is). Once you have confirmed this works, you can string commands together across hosts:

```
# On the local host
xargs rm -r < deletion_list.txt

# Also on the local host connnecting to the remote
ssh user@remotehost xargs rm -r < delete_list.txt
```

What that second command does is to connect to the remote system and run `xargs rm -r` on it, feeding its *stdin* from your local file called `delete_list.txt`.